# How do I install packages like Oracle Java?

Tags: installation, package-management, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Oracle Java JRE 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7)

I've been trying to install various things, and I need some packages that just aren't showing up in Ubuntu's Software Center. In fact, no packages are showing up there, just whole programs. I need to install `sun-java6-jre` for some of these things, but it's simply not in the Software Center. I had Ubuntu last year (and due to various circumstances, had to get rid of it shortly thereafter) and these things were there then. So why can't I find them now?